# How would I go about replacing this function in my child theme located in inc/template-tags.php

Tags: functions, filters, child-theme, parent-theme

How would I replace this function that lies inside `inc/template-tags.php` in my parent theme

```
function theme_navigation() {
?>
        
        <div id="theme-nav-container">
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
                <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'theme-studios-primary', 'menu_class' => 'sf-menu', 'fallback_cb' => false, 'walker'  => new theme ) ); ?><div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
            </nav>
            <div class="clearfix-pro"></div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- close #theme-nav-container -->
        
        
<?php
}
```

There is no add action that it is hooked on to, there is no check to see if the function already exists. How would I replace it without touching the parent theme. I have removed much of the code in the function for brevity but I think it still makes sense.

Thanks ahead of time

Comment: If the function is defined in the global scope in your parent theme, and you cannot alter the parent theme, then I don't think there is much you can do about it. But you can possibly overwrite the parent template file that calls `theme_navigation` with a child theme file.

Comment: yeah just realized it's referenced in header.php, so I am just overwriting that now. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't replace the function, but you can substitute it:

1. Copy the function to your child theme's functions file.
2. Rename the function.
3. Modify it as needed.
4. Find the template file that references it, such as header.php, and copy that to your child theme.
5. In your child theme's new template file replace the reference to the original function with your renamed version.

Comment: prefect that's what I ended up doing thanks for answering this. Now it's in my vault for when I need to go back and check ;)